# How to get unsaved editor input in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to get the current editor content (for default editor) and export it to a file (for my Eclipse plugin).

For example, say the programmer has opened file test.java, which has following 2 lines:

```
System.out.println("Line 1");
System.out.println("Line 2");
```

But then he added a new line like following but did not save it.

```
System.out.println("Line 1");
System.out.println("Line 2");
System.out.println("Line 3");
```

I want to export this to a file without saving the document. How can I do it?

(Basically, my plugin will try to compute a block difference with original file at the beginning. But if the programmer start typing in editor before it is executed (as the difference calculation can take time for large files), then the listener will pause the program and the block difference computation will start again, once the programmer has stopped typing)

**My attempt:**
I can get the editor input as follow:

```
   IDocument document = MyMarkerPlugin.getEditor()
            .getDocumentProvider()
            .getDocument(MyMarkerPlugin.getEditor().getEditorInput());
```

But I don't know how to export a document of type Idocument to a file. Couldn't find any api regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDocument` has a `get` method to return you the text of the document:

```
String text = document.get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was needed. I used the BufferedWriter and FileWriter to create a file from this string.